# Show example text in textbox in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ViewModel for my partial view I have Email defined like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

In the view I have this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I would like something like 'example@company.com' to appear in the textbox as a placeholder or example. But right now it is empty.

Comment: Other posts did not include the @ for the @placeholder statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute (HTML5) to the form element. Browsers which supports this feature will add a placeholder text to your textbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Email, new { @class="form-control", placeholder="sample@ss.com"})
```

Comment: Nice repeat answer... `placeholder` doesn't need an @ as it's not a reserved word btw

Comment: You don't need the @ other than for reserved words in C# when specifying your HTML attributes.  It's a bit strange that the correct answer check was moved from the first answer and the proper way of doing things to an ill-formatted answer provided later that has non-required additional syntax and doesn't even make use of the existing code that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add a `placeholder` attribute to your HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "example@company.com"})
```